# Why is this method ambiguous?

Tags: java, mongodb, overloading

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMongoDAO<T extends AbstractChiliEntity> implements IDAO<ObjectId, T> {

   // Method 1    
   protected List<DBObject> getByQuery(Object... pairs) {
       DBObject dbobject = //...
       return getByQuery(dbobject);
   }

   // Method 2    
   protected List<DBObject> getByQuery(Map<String, Object> map) {
       DBObject dbobject = //...
       return getByQuery(dbobject);
   }

   // Method 3
   protected List<DBObject> getByQuery(DBObject query) {
       List<DBObject> dbobjects = //...
       return dbobjects;
   }

   // Inherited methods here - they have nothing at all to do with the methods above.
}
```

Method 1 and 2 are simply different approaches to constructing a DBObject, which is then passed to Method 3 in order to query a MongoDB instance and return a set of results.

The compiler complains at the return statement of method 1 and 2:

```
The method getByQuery(Object[]) is ambiguous for the type AbstractMongoDAO<T>
```

Why is this? The program compiles if I comment out method 2. If I comment out method 1, however, I get the same compiler error, but for method 2 instead.

Comment: Tried with my compiler, don’t have any problems. In method 2 `dbobjects` had to get changed to `dbobject` but that’s all. Make sure your example contains really everything to reproduce the problem. Oh, or tell us the Java version you use. I tried `javac` from Java 6 to 8 and the eclipse compiler with the same result.

Comment: Holger is right there is nothing wrong on the code except from the Wrong variable name in method 2. 

On  the other and varargs was introduced on java 1.5 and the had to made some decisións about how JVM choose the method to execute on runtime. You may take a look to how the selection of the method to execute is taken by the JVM. 

Take a look to http://goo.gl/G7UbGb

Comment: Yes, I think this might simply be an Eclipse issue...the code looked perfectly fine to me as well, hence why I was puzzled about the errors.  Will confirm when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a problem with Eclipse, which reports this an an error when it simply isn't. I will file a bug report.

Eclipse version used is the Java EE build based on Eclipse 4.3, build id: 20130919-0819.